# Extrema of $f(\theta)=cos(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What is the minimum and maximum of $$f(\theta)=\cos(\theta)$$ and what values of theta do they occur at?

I have tried multiple ways to solve this and seem to continue to get it wrong. I feel that I am making a very simple mistake and would like to see each step so I can learn.

Comment: What is $f'(\theta)$ ?

Comment: "I have tried multiple ways to solve this", like what?

Comment: You have to say that $\theta$ is real because for complex $\theta$, the question may not even make sense.

Comment: Look at its graph, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Recall from trigonometry
$$
| \cos \theta | \le 1.
$$
The plot of $\cos \theta$ is shown below for $-2\pi < \theta < 2\pi$.

[image: cos]

In calculus we look for extrema by identifying the points where the first derivative is zero. Solve
$$
 f'(\theta) = D_{\theta}\left( \cos \theta \right) = - \sin \theta = 0
$$
The solution is 
$$
  \theta = 2 k \pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Are the extrema maxima or minima? We must look at the second derivate. If $f''(\theta) > 0$, we are at a minimum. When $f''(\theta) < 0$, we are at a maximum.

Evaluate 
$$
 f''(\theta) = D_{\theta}\left(D_{\theta}\left( \cos \theta \right)\right) = D_{\theta}\left( - \sin \theta \right) = - \cos \theta
$$
at the $\theta$ values from above.

When the angle is an even multiple of $\pi$, 
$$
  \theta = 2 k \pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
we have a maximum. When the angle is an odd multiple of $\pi$, 
$$
  \theta = (2 k + 1) \pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
we have a minimum.